# Regex capturing many times same group

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem for several hours on something yet simple but i can't find a correct solution. I have sentences like this:

> "John teach {french|english} in {Paris|New York} since {5|6} years".

I have to extract each part between braces in order to get that:

> - french|english
> - Paris|New York
> - 5|6

I've tried with this regular expression :

```
    (\{.*\|.*\})
```

I do not know why it sucks because i try to capture the good string i think.
I'tried with many other regex, whithout success.

If someone can help me, i thank him :-)

Comment: You can use: `/({[^|]*\|[^}]*})/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below lines of code if you are looking to do this with php.

```
$content ="John teach {french|english} in {Paris|New York} since {5|6} years";
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $content, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $result){
    echo $result;
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much.